# External Sharing - Sent to wrong email. What happens next?

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-sharing

I am wondering if i type in an wrong/non existent email-adress when sharing a site?

What happens? Do i receive an bounced email that the delivery was not successful?

Is there a way to track this use-case?

Answer (score 1):

Site Settings should display a link called "Access requests and invitations" under the usual "People and Groups" and "Site permissions" - this is only visible once an invite for that site has been sent out.

In there you can withdraw invitations. The link will be invalid so even if the wrong person received it, when they finally click it they won't be granted access.

You won't receive a bounced email because the message doesn't originate from your mailbox.

I hope this helps - if you can't access that settings page I can go into more detail about using PowerShell to remove an external user

Comment: Thanks, i know that. Is there a way to change which mailbox the email is sent from?

I am trying to do an onboarding with a lot of external users with powershell script and would like to know if an invite email has been sent to a mailbox that dosen't exist.

Comment: On SharePoint Online it always just comes from "no-reply@sharepoint.com". I'm not sure about granting access with PS sadly, sorry but perhaps the cmdlet you're using has documentation about a possible argument or switch that can enable error reporting?